# How do I use the tkinter variable in my code?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm practicing how to make a GUI with Tkinter, however I am unsure how to fix this code, any help is greatly appreciated. I want the label to change with button inputs, however it doesn't even show at all. The only out put from the label is PY_VAR0

```
class Window(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("My Window")
        self.label_text = tk.StringVar()
        self.label_text.set("Choose One:")

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text=self.label_text)
        self.label.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1, padx=150, pady=30)

        hello_button = tk.Button(self, text="Say Hello",bg='black',fg='white',
                                 command=self.say_hello)
        hello_button.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(20,0), pady=(0,20))

        goodbye_button = tk.Button(self, text="Say Goodbye",bg='black',fg='white',
                                   command=self.say_goodbye)
        goodbye_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=(0,20), pady=(0,20))



    def say_hello(self):
        self.label_text.set("Hello there!")
    def say_goodbye(self):
        self.label_text.set("See you next time!\n(Closing in 2 seconds)")
        self.after(2000, self.destroy)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    window=Window()
    window.mainloop()
```

Comment: When creating your Label you should pass the StringVar `self.label_text` as `textvariable` instead of as `text`. When you pass it as `text` the object will be converted to a string and `str(tk.StringVar())` results in `"PY_VARx"`. Passing it as `textvariable` tells tkinter to use the `get()` function on the object to get the string instead.

Answer (score 0):

You need to link the variable with the label. Instead, you're attempting to set the variable itself as the text of the label.

Replace this:

```
self.label = tk.Label(self, text=self.label_text)
```

... with this:

```
self.label = tk.Label(self, textvariable=self.label_text)
```